# Android 7(AOSP): Wifi: Disable RSSI polling

Tags: android, wifi, android-source, android-wifi

is there any possibility to dynamically disable RSSI polling in the `WifiStateMachine` of Android 7? I know that the polling intervall
can be modified in config.xml, but then it is static for one build.

The command for polling is at `enter()` of the L2ConnectedState:

```
if (mEnableRssiPolling) {
  sendMessage(CMD_RSSI_POLL, mRssiPollToken, 0);
}
```

Enable is set whenever the `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` broadcast is published:

```
ACTION_SCREEN_ON->CMD_SCREEN_STATE_CHANGED->
handleScreenStateChanged()->enableRssiPolling()->
CMD_ENABLE_RSSI_POLL
```

Is there any config entry, which allows it to be disabled during runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a possibility, so I wrote a patch for `wifiStateMachine.java`.
The next issue was to apply the Patch during build time before the wifi module is
built. This is further investigated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60551915/1849612) question.